# How to get object from data returned from Ajax call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/ajax.php",
    data: $('#form-responder').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data); // prints: {"sucesso":"true", "mensagem":"Correta: A pulseira de identificação se aplica a todos os pacientes, sem exceção. ", "index_proxima":"2"}
        //var sucesso = eval(data.sucesso);
        var mensagem = data.mensagem;
        alert(mensagem); // shows: undefined
    }
});
```

I need to get some object values but all of them are returning 'undefined', what is wrong with that? 
I used to do data.something and always worked before, maybe something with this jQuery version 2.1.3 ?

Comment: You need to specify  `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call if you 're returning json data.

Comment: Try add `async: false` or check link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [parseJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63zqg8rq/1/)

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON( data);
alert(data.mensagem);
```

Comment: jQuery will automatically do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

`"mensagem"` is string key, you should use it with array key format like so: `data['mensagem']`.

```js
var data = {"sucesso":"true", "mensagem":"Correta: A pulseira de identificação se aplica a todos os pacientes, sem exceção. ", "index_proxima":"2"};

$('input').val(data['mensagem']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```